# EF5 Code First - Changing A Column Type With Migrations

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am new to EF5 Code First and I'm tinkering with a proof-of-concept before embarking on a project at work.

I have initially created a model that looked something like

```
public class Person {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set;}
  public string Surname {get;set;}
  public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

And I added a few records using a little MVC application I stuck on the top.

Now I want to change the Location column to an enum, something like:

```
public class Person {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set;}
  public string Surname {get;set;}
  public Locations Location {get;set;}
}

public enum Locations {
  London = 1,
  Edinburgh = 2,
  Cardiff = 3
}
```

When I add the new migration I get:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.People", "Location", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
```

but when I run update-database I get an error

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'London' to data type int.
```

Is there a way in the migration to truncate the table before it runs the alter statement?

I know I can open the database and manually do it, but is there a smarter way?

Comment: I'd suggest for developers in similar positions that they see if the conversion is handled automatically by Entity Framework before following some of the answers on this page. For example, I found it handles the conversion between a string and a decimal and back again with no help from me - the migration that Add-Migration generated works fine. Obviously, try it out on a local/test database before applying it to production!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The smartest way is probably to not alter types. If you need to do this, I'd suggest you to do the following steps:

1. Add a new column with your new type
2. Use `Sql()` to take over the data from the original column using an update statement
3. Remove the old column
4. Rename the new column

This can all be done in the same migration, the correct SQL script will be created. You can skip step 2 if you want your data to be discarded. If you want to take it over, add the appropriate statement (can also contain a switch statement).

Unfortunately Code First Migrations do not provide easier ways to accomplish this.

Here is the example code:

```
AddColumn("dbo.People", "LocationTmp", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
Sql(@"
    UPDATE dbp.People
    SET LocationTmp =
        CASE Location
            WHEN 'London' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Edinburgh' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Cardiff' THEN 3
            ELSE 0
        END
    ");
DropColumn("dbo.People", "Location");
RenameColumn("dbo.People", "LocationTmp", "Location");
```

Comment: A quick note: using a temporary column is the only way I've found to do this when migrating `Down()`. The schema updates appear to be running inside a transaction that also contains the `Sql()` command, as a column update from the `Integer` values back to `String` fail with the same error message—this time on `Sql()` instead of `AlterColumn()`. This even though we run `Sql()` AFTER `AlterColumn()`.

Answer (score 28):

Based on @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow's answer, but easier.

Try firstly execute `Sql()` command and then `AlterColumn()`:

```
Sql(@"
    UPDATE dbo.People
    SET Location =
        CASE Location
            WHEN 'London' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Edinburgh' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Cardiff' THEN 3
            ELSE 0
        END
    ");
AlterColumn("dbo.People", "Location", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
```

Comment: I like it more than the marked answer: It doesn't need a temporary column.

Answer (score 4):

I know this doesn't apply directly to the question but could be helpful to someone. In my problem, I accidentally made a year field a datetime and I was trying to figure out how to delete all the data and then switch the data type to an int.

When doing an add-migration, EF wanted to just update the column. I had to delete what they wanted to do and add my own code. I basically just dropped the column and added a new column. Here is what worked for me.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "TestingPeriodYear",
            table: "ControlActivityIssue");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "TestingPeriodYear",
            table: "ControlActivityIssue",
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "TestingPeriodYear",
            table: "ControlActivityIssue");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "TestingPeriodYear",
            table: "ControlActivityIssue",
            nullable: true);
    }
```

Comment: Can't do that on a system with existing data

Answer (score 0):

***If you are using PostgreSQL:***

[In PostgreSQL, when there's a possibility of data loss, adding a USING clause is necessary to be able to delete data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26439033/11123185). Unfortunately, there isn't an automated feature in Entity Framework that handles this. When generating a migration, if you replace the alter part of the column in the example provided below, you can take a migration without encountering any issues during the update-database process.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql($@" ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE integer USING (column_name::integer); ");
```