# Updating a column type and updating data with non-SQL code

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net

I have a table of `Result` objects (called `Results`). Currently, one column of this table is a `string` type called `ResultsData`, and represents a Json serialization of a C# object (using Json.NET).

Due to problems with the size of these objects leading to database queries timing out, I want to change this column to a `byte[]`, holding a Bson serialization of the object. However, when I change the type, add a migration and run it, it understandably crashes, as `string` objects have no implicit conversion to `byte[]`. The `Up()` method for the migration, for reference, looks like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.Results", "ResultsData", c => c.Binary());
}
```

I should mention that any data loss here is unacceptable.

Now I can handle the code to convert individual strings to byte arrays, and it's in a method that we'll call `byte[] ConvertResult(string resultsData)`. What I'm not sure about is how I'd call this method on each row of the database.

The closest answer that I could find on here is the first answer of this question: [EF5 Code First - Changing A Column Type With Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837168/ef5-code-first-changing-a-column-type-with-migrations). However, the conversion code in that case is done entirely in SQL, which obviously does not apply here.

If anyone has any ideas as to how I might go about this, it'd be greatly appreciated. The version of Entity Framework I'm running is 6.1.3, if that helps.

### Edit

Out of desperation, I tried putting the actual conversion code into the SQL method: didn't expect it to work, and it didn't, producing the error `Incorrect syntax near 'END'`:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Results", "ResultsDataTmp", c => c.Binary());
    Sql(@"
    UPDATE dbo.Results
    SET ResultsDataTmp = Service.ConvertOldResultsToBinary(ResultsData)
        END
    ");
    DropColumn("dbo.Results", "ResultsData");
    RenameColumn("dbo.Results", "ResultsDataTmp", "ResultsData");
}
```

### Edit 2

Here's the implementation of `Serial.ConvertOldResultsToBinary`, as per DrewJordan's request.

```
public byte[] ConvertOldResultsToBinary (string oldResultsData)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer
    {
        ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
    };

    IResultsWrapper result;

    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(oldResultsData)))
    {
        try
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize<ResultsWrapper>(reader);
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException)
        {
            using (var trialReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(oldResultsData)))
                {
                    result = serializer.Deserialize<TrialResultsWrapper>(trialReader);
            }
        }
    }

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var writer = new BsonWriter(stream))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, result);
    }
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The specific error given, if it helps, is:
`Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

Comment: what is done in `Service.ConvertOldResultsToBinary`? can you post it?

Comment: @DrewJordan sorry for the late reply, just edited the question to include this code. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Your first edit was on the right track, you need to convert to binary in SQL, however you can't call C# code inside of the call to `Sql()` since you're telling it to simply run the string you pass as a SQL command.

Try something like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Results", "ResultsDataTmp", c => c.Binary());
    Sql(@"
    UPDATE dbo.Results
    SET ResultsDataTmp = CAST(ResultsData AS VARBINARY(MAX))
        END
    ");
    DropColumn("dbo.Results", "ResultsData");
    RenameColumn("dbo.Results", "ResultsDataTmp", "ResultsData");
}
```