# How to change the property type of a column Ef6 code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Im aware of this post: [EF5 Code First - Changing A Column Type With Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837168/ef5-code-first-changing-a-column-type-with-migrations). I cant leave a comment to ask my question because of my rep so. Concerning the best answer, what goes in the Up() and what goes in the Down().

Comment: Can you give more information? What are you wanting to change from/to?

Comment: How is your use case different from the post you mentioned? What are the column type you are trying to alter, in simple use case you will only need AlterColumn function in both Up and Down.

Comment: @Kevin R. wanting to change a type from string to int.

Comment: but i came across this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894906/ef-migration-for-changing-data-type-of-columns that answered my questions