# Migration Error in Entity Framework with Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Code First, and I want to migrate it to ORACLE database, after multiple migrations process,  I am getting this error,

> The best overloaded method match for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.CreateTableOperation) has some invalid arguments

Comment: Im facing the same problem when a migration involves a RenameIndex operation, seems like the Generate overload for RenameIndexOperation is not implemented in OracleMigrationSqlGenerator

Comment: @oskr Remove migration history not right solution. Because when database on production and need to apply some migration at time what we need to ? Because if we delete MigrationHistory so we again need to setup entire db. I am looking some good solution. Please let me know if any good solution to prevent this error when apply migration on existing Oracle DB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem 
finally I solve it by opening the database and delete the migration_history table manually
and run the command again.
see at [EF5 Code First - Changing A Column Type With Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837168/ef5-code-first-changing-a-column-type-with-migrations)

Answer (score 0):

in each migration you will save a record in `__MigrationHistory`, so in case there is no sync between the code and the migration do the following:

1. delete the migration history table in the database.
2. migrate it again by create new migration 'in package manager console' `add-migration data`.
3. update the migration to database `update-database`

Comment: `delete the migration history table in the database` why not change PC?