# Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on colum Entity frame Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

how to solve this error in migration i am using old developer code i don't know how do this i spend 3 4 hours in this but not solve please any one help me

> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on column 'vOid' in table
>   'table1'. The computed column has to be persisted and not nullable.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

```
       public Guid VOid { get; set; }

 entity.HasKey(e => e.VOid)
                    .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);

         entity.Property(e => e.VOid)
                            .HasColumnName("vOid")
                            .HasComputedColumnSql("(CONVERT([uniqueidentifier],json_value([value],'$._id'),(0)))")
                            .ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Comment: That error tells you all you need to know, what about it do you not understand?

Comment: i am new in Entity please solve this

Comment: That;s not an EF error, it's a SQL Server error.

Comment: then how to solve this ..? using code first

Comment: Do some research first, that might help...

Comment: i already spend 3 4 hours

Comment: i am creating database using EF code first , how to solve this error

Comment: Have you tried with `[Required]` attribute on `VOid` property?

Comment: yes dear .......

Comment: still pending this issue

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to see the table structure you are referring to, but I assume, as the error says, that the column should be "not nullable". You could give this a try:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN vOid INT NOT NULL
GO
```

Comment: i am creating database using EF code first , how to solve this error

Comment: @JOhns If you need to know how to change the SQL Server Column type to set it to not nullable, using EF - you could refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837349/8819015)